# Chrome extension getting ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT when using chrome.windows.create with incognito: true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im making a chrome extension and its almost working fine. I have different scripts etc. The code in my background.js is the problem:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL('public/index.html'),
    type: 'popup',
    incognito: true
  }, function(tab) {
    // Tab opened.
  });
});
```

When I click the extension badge in the top right corner of chrome a window pops up as it should. Only problem is that im getting this:

```
dpdjdlpkjggdlgipmfcingfflcleechd is blocked
Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
Try disabling your extensions.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

And when i remove the incognito: true property from the options it's working fine.

Anyone who knows why? 
Or anyone who knows how to make the popup not reopenable after it has been closed (CTRL+SHIFT+T) (that is the main goal)?

Comment: What else plugins do you have on your browser?Do you have any antivirus installed?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito): you need to specify "split" mode.

Comment: Thank you! Specifying "incognito": "split" in the manifest file did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Specifically, please include at least a minimal *manifest.json* showing that the setting you are using for `incognito` is not `split`. Then future readers can definitively know that the problem is and the solution.